# How to change subscription on Azure old portal?

Tags: azure, azureportal

First of all, why microsoft azure changed the portal UI? In my opinion the oldest is much more clear. 
But the question is, i have multiple subscriptions associated with my live id email. When i go to **manage.windowsazure.com** url and log with my live id, i go to a default subscription, but i need to change it staying on the old portal. Where can i find this option?
On the configuration menu i have just these options:
[image: azuremenu]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the top right corner before configuration menu, you will see `Subscriptions` filter. Clicking on that will show you all the directories your account is associated with. You can change the directory and can filter subscriptions you wish to see. Please see the screenshot below for more details:

[image]

Comment: Hi, i changed to the new portal, and now i cannot go back to the old portal. I just cannot find a link saying somethin "back to the classic portal".

Comment: You may try accessing old portal by opening it in private browser window or by deleting all cookies/clearing browser cache.

Comment: didnt work. i found this link https://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-portal/suggestions/10287573-i-can-t-access-old-portal-manage-windowsazure-red . My subscription is "contributor". I need to change it, but i cant find the 'classic service/co-admin access' option.

Comment: As a contributor, you don't have access to manage permissions. Only service admins and co-admins can manage co-admin access from the old portal.